# Ping time increases in every 10th try and then gets back to normal

Tags: networking, ping

I have tested this problem only on my machine but in different regions and different ISPs.

When I ping a server, time is ok, but not in 10th try. Look:

```
C:\Users\Aryan>ping google.com -t

Pinging google.com [216.58.205.238] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=165ms TTL=44 
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=1232ms TTL=44 // HIGH TIME HERE
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=165ms TTL=44 // Ok 1
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=166ms TTL=44 // Ok 2
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=166ms TTL=44 // Ok 3
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=165ms TTL=44 // Ok 4
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=165ms TTL=44 // Ok 5
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=167ms TTL=44 // Ok 6
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=166ms TTL=44 // Ok 7
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=169ms TTL=44 // Ok 8
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=165ms TTL=44 // Ok 9
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=951ms TTL=44 // NEXT HIGH TIME, on 10th
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=166ms TTL=44
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=165ms TTL=44
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=165ms TTL=44
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=165ms TTL=44
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=166ms TTL=44
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=166ms TTL=44
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=165ms TTL=44
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=165ms TTL=44
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=166ms TTL=44
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=900ms TTL=44 // AND NEXT
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=166ms TTL=44
Reply from 216.58.205.238: bytes=32 time=164ms TTL=44
```

As another example:

```
C:\Users\Aryan>ping blog.ir -t

Pinging blog.ir [91.99.101.242] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=1045ms TTL=53 // HIGH TIME
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=963ms TTL=53 // AND AGAIN
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=893ms TTL=53 // AND AGAIN
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=53
Reply from 91.99.101.242: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=53
```

As you see, for any site I have tried till now, ping on exactly 10th try jumps to a high number and then gets down.

Why is this happening?

When I'm playing an online game, everything stops for a while and then gets back to normal. Is it related to this kind of ping jumping?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this occur when you ping your gateway/router? Are you using a cable or is this wifi? Do a tracert and then do ping tests on the first 2 or 3 hops.

Comment: Your WiFi interface's roaming aggressiveness setting is probably too high. You can lower it on its properties page.

Comment: Does the `-w` flag let DOS ping send more than one packet per second?

   `ping google.com -t -w 400`


Also, what does `ping localhost -t` look like, as well as your router's IP?

I suspect something is pausing your system's networking every 10 seconds; are you running any bandwidth monitoring apps or widgets?

Try booting up in safe-networking mode and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I second @DavidSchwartz. If this is on Wi-Fi, look for things on your system triggering periodic Wi-Fi scans, such as roaming thresholds, Wi-Fi geolocation, and Wi-Fi network scanner widgets.

Comment: @Yorik It occurs when I ping my gateway, but not when pinging localhost. All trace route hops times out. I am using Wifi.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My adapter roaming aggressiveness is set to "4. Normal". Is it high? Should I change it to "3. Medium low" , "2. Lowest" or "1. Disabled" ?

Comment: @NevinWilliams executing `ping google.com -t -w 400` pings google without this kind of ping jumps, but with a lot of time outs between successful packets. Localhost is ok, but gateway (wifi modem) has this issue. I don't have any wifi monitoring apps, but I will try safe-networking mode.

Comment: Your WiFi adapter might just suck. You might also have some other program or tool running that's causing it to scan. Lowering the roaming aggressiveness might help. (You may want to turn off its power management. WiFI power management is really only needed for phones and tablets and it does cause intermittent losses of connectivity.)

Comment: Normally, ping sends one packet per second;  does using the -w 400 option send them faster than once per second?   If so, do you have trouble periodically, around the 10 second mark?  (might be a cluster of missed packets.)  

I think @DavidSchwartz's suggestion is probably a good place to continue, if safe mode w/ networking still shows the problem.

Comment: @Spiff I turned off firewall, AV Protection, System location service and any tool that i thought it might affect network functionality but nothing changed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I first set roaming aggressiveness to lowest and then completely disabled it in the second try. In both cases problem resists (: Power management was off too.

Comment: @NevinWilliams I don't know whats happening in the background, but ping results are written in CLI every 1 second it seems, not faster. And there are a lot of timed out results.

Comment: It seems it is not possible to enable WIFI adapter in my version of Windows 10 when in safe with networking mode. So I pinged my gateway with Linux OS and everything was fine. After it, I pinged again with Windows and it is now pinging correctly without jumping!

Comment: do you have e.g. HP Wifi adapter "helper" style software running (any OEM stuff really)? If so, you might try disabling that and let winodws handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was **Free Download Manager 5** that was blocking network every 10 seconds. When I closed it, everything worked fine and when I reopened it, the problem started again.